# Codeigniter - image uploading

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am trying to store the following html string as well as the image referenced in the string in the data base.

```
<p> Text before the image</p> <p> <img alt="" src="axe.png" 200px; height: 163px;" /></p> <p> &nbsp;</p> <p> Text after image</p>
```

I am using Codeigniter's Upload library. Accordingly, I config the "upload_path" correctly on the server side. I pass in the name of the image file as one of the fields in the AJAX call ('img_fname') to the server.

But when I call

```
$this->upload->do_upload('img_fname')
```

it says "no file to upload".
I am definitely missing the forest for the trees! Please help!

Mmiz

Comment: CI ``do_upload()`` function try to upload file from ``$_FILES[]`` array. You get this error because you ``$_FILES[]`` array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your upload form shoud include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
2. your file input field should named `img_fname`
3. `<img alt="" src="axe.png" 200px; height: 163px;" />` should be `<img alt="" src="axe.png" style="200px; height: 163px;" />`

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for the slow acceptance. My time was hijacked by another project. Thanks again.